# How to do state restoration in Flutter 2 without StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, state-restoration

I am fairly new to Flutter. I am using Flutter 2 ChangeNotifiers to share state between multiple StatelessWidget-derived screens. That lets me have truly declarative UI and navigation, with no StatefulWidgets used in my app explicitly. Everything works fine.

Now I would like to implement state restoration, but all Flutter state restoration examples rely on StatefulWidgets, effectively requiring potentially shared state to be associated with some specific widget just for the restoration purpose, even though my use case is shared state used by multiple stateless widgets. I mean I haven't had a need for StatefulWidgets so far and it feels like a really bad anti-pattern having to switch to StatefulWidgets just for state restoration and then try to figure out how multiple StatefulWidgets using some single piece of state are supposed to restore it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RestorableChangeNotifier-class.html?

Comment: If you could provide an example of how to use it, or some other insight, I would appreciate it. I was aware of this class and the docs only say it's a base class for the RestorableProperty which in turn requires a StatefulWidget to be registered with.

Comment: I haven't really got in depth of your problem. I haven't implemented this particular class yet. 
But I also don't really get why you don't want to use stateful widgets if you want to manage state.
"A stateless widget never changes" flutter.dev
What kind of state does your ChnageNotifier have?

Comment: The reason to not use StatefulWidget is that my understanding that StatefulWidgets are appropriate when a given piece of state is used by one specific widget. ChangeNotifier-based state structures seem to be a better fit and recommended pattern for cases when a piece of state is shared between multiple Widgets. I am open to usage of StatefulWidgets if I could see an example where shared state is used efficiently with with them, without introducing code/functionality duplication.